# Using +(NSData *) to read back file

Tags: objective-c, encryption, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use [this project](https://github.com/nerdcave/encrypt-assets) to do just what it says, encrypt some assets in my application bundle. The command line tool works just fine for encrypting the files, but I'm lost when it comes to trying to read my file at run-time. I basically just have one file that I need to load which uses NSDictionary, but the call for unencrypting the file make no sense to me.

My Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];
```

The Code to Decrypt:

```
-(NSData*) decryptedWithKey:(NSData*)key;
```

I have no idea what the heck to do with that? help!

Here's the project on github > https://github.com/nerdcave/encrypt-assets

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the dictionary directly with `initWithContentsOfFile:` because the file is encrypted, so you need to load the file data and decrypt it first:

```
NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:...];
NSData *decryptedData = [fileData decryptedWithKey:...];
```

Now, you need to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to get a dictionary from the unencrypted data:

```
NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: decryptedData options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:nil error:&error];
```

(using `NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves` so the dictionary, and contents, are mutable).

Comment: Hi - I have one error when using `NSData *decryptedData = [fileData decryptedWithKey:@"1234"];`, which states incompatible pointer types sending NSString to parameter of type NSData. I might not be using the key correctly I assume? thank you!

Comment: Because you are setting the `key` to the string @"1234" when it expects an `NSData` instance. Look at using `[@"1234" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]` (though note that I haven't looked at the github page to check what the data should be...)